# Laravel 5.8 Unit Test Mail : Mailable was not sent

Tags: laravel, email, phpunit

I am writing a PHPUnit feature test for send email by Laravel 5.8 but i got error `Mailable was not sent`

This is my code :

```
class AccountVerificationTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $authUser;
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $user = $this->createAdminUser();
        $this->be($user, 'admin');
        $this->authUser = $user;
    }

    public function testSendMailPass()
    {
        Mail::fake();
        $user = $this->authUser;
        Mail::assertNothingSent(AccountVerification::class);
        Mail::assertSent(AccountVerification::class, function ($email) use ($user) {
            return $this->assertEquals('Subject', $email->subject) &&
            $email->hasTo($user->email);
        });
    }
}
```

Send Mail feature still work but false in test. Please tell me where i am wrong

Comment: So tell me where exactly in your test are you sending the mail that you want the mail fake to catch?

Comment: thank you ! I add Mail::to()->send() and everthing ok